# Windows Force shutdown command not work

Tags: java, cmd, shutdown

i use this command for shutdown :

```
shutdown.exe -s -t 00
```

and this command work successfully

but force shudown does not work :

```
shutdown.exe –s –f –t 00
```

also i'm using windows 10 ..

what's the problem?

(i use this commands in my java application)

Comment: When you say it does not work, what happens? Is there an error in the console? Do applications exit but the machine stays on?

Comment: No,when enter this commnad nothing happen .

Comment: Yet `shutdown.exe -s -t 00` shuts down your machine properly? Can you post the code in your java application you are using to run the command?

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec(shutdownCommand);

Comment: There's no reason I can think of why one would work but not the other. What version of windows are you using?

Comment: Windows 10 build 10240

Comment: [It looks like that build has given some people shutdown-related issues](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_update/shutdown-problem-with-windows-10-build-10240/14f0e069-9384-4a0c-af4c-0a1664ea62f5?auth=1). I would try updating your machine, if nothing else.

Comment: Have you checked the system event logs for any messages related to the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the following command:

```
shutdown –s –f –t 00
```

where `00` is the waiting time (in seconds) before your computer forces shutdown. The allowed range for the waiting time is `0 - 315360000` seconds (0 seconds - 10 years), with a default of `30` seconds.

Comment: @Abolfazi74 Does my answer work? If so, please mark it as accepted so as to not leave any open questions hanging around in SO :)

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following command:

```
shutdown –s -f –t 0
```

Comment: I don't see any `-force` argument [in the docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/bb491003.aspx). Have you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

When I am in my **Window** this command works perfectly:
`shutdown /f /p`

**/p** for shutdown
**/f** for forcing